# Database "mem:" not found, and IFEXISTS=true when I am trying to connect ht2 database

Tags: java, database, maven, spring-boot, h2

I have basic spring boot application that has 4 microservises. Discovery Service , Api Gateway Service (Zuul) , UsersMicorservise and Accounts Microservice

I am trying to add h2 in-memory database to my User Service but when I am loading the h2-console and pressing connect I am getting this message

[image]

These are my application.properties

```
server.port=${PORT:0}
spring.application.name=users-ws
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone = http://localhost:8010/eureka
spring.devtools.restart.enabled = true
eureka.instance.instance-id=${spring.application.name}:${spring.application.instance_id:${random.value}}


# H2
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.settings.web-allow-others=true
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:test
```

And this is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.8.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.appsdeveloperblog.photoapp.api.users</groupId>
    <artifactId>PhotoAppApiUsers</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>PhotoAppApiUsers</name>
    <description>Users microservice</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.SR3</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:test;IFEXISTS=FALSE;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console
```

[IFEXISTS](http://h2database.com/html/features.html#database_only_if_exists)

OR

*Downgrade to 1.3.170*

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.170</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```